# Moving a file from a directory to a success directory or an error directory with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to implement a Spring Integration class that takes a .xml file parses it and if it's valid move it to an "archived" directory and in case of invalidity move it to an error directory.

```
import com.nagarro.studentapi.integration.queue.StudentSender;
import com.nagarro.studentapi.util.XmlParser;
import org.aopalliance.aop.Advice;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileHeaders;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.support.FileExistsMode;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;

import java.io.File;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    private static final String XML = "*.xml";
    private static final String STUDENT = "\\student.xml";

    @Value("${student-api.xmlPath}")
    private String inputPath;
    @Value("${student-api.archivedDestination}")
    private String successPath;
    @Value("${student-api.errorDestination}")
    private String errorPath;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel messageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "messageChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> messageProducer() {
        FileReadingMessageSource messageSource = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDirectory(new File(inputPath));
        messageSource.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(XML));
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "messageChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(successPath));
        handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        handler.setExpectReply(false);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(XmlParser xmlParser) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(messageProducer(), spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, "payload"))
                .convert(String.class)
                .transform((String path) -> xmlParser.parsePath(path))
                .handle("xmlParser", "parsePath", e -> e.advice(errorAdvice()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice errorAdvice() {
        return new AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
                File file = message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class);
                try {
                    Object result = callback.execute();
                    file.renameTo(new File(successPath, STUDENT));
                    System.out.println("File renamed after success");
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    file.renameTo(new File(errorPath, STUDENT));
                    System.out.println("File renamed after failure");
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

However whenever `calback.execute()` it's called I get this error and I don't quite understand why.

```
2022-09-06 18:20:07.971 ERROR 32152 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1135e3d6]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=Student(firstname=John, lastname=Dose, cnp=123, birthDate=2000-12-12, address=Address(street=a, number=1, city=Craiova, country=Romania), grades=[Grade(discipline=a, date=2021-12-12, grade=10), Grade(discipline=b, date=2021-12-12, grade=9)]), headers={....
```

Although I have a message handler I suspect the reason for this problem is that i do not override the handle method. But i am unsure of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problem:

1. `@InboundChannelAdapter` and `IntegrationFlows.from(messageProducer()`. This way you create two independent polling endpoints for the same source.
2. `@ServiceActivator` - the endpoint to write has just read file from one of the sources.
3. There is no connection between `@InboundChannelAdapter`, your `@ServiceActivator` expectations and that flow.
4. You have `.transform((String path) -> xmlParser.parsePath(path))` and then immediately after that `handle("xmlParser", "parsePath")` which looks, essentially the same, but does not make sense since you are going to call the same `parsePath()` twice, but for different payloads, where the second one is going to be as a result of the first `parsePath()` call.

Please, revise your logic carefully: right now some of your configuration is misleading and really error-prone. I believe that error you got is because your `parsePath()` expects a `String`, but not `Student` as we see in the payload for that `handle()`.